# got SIGSEGV while calling 'require ("lsqlite3")' with lua 5.1.5

Tags: lua

I had built lua 5.1.5 and lsqlite3-0.8.1. all of them run well on my RedHat Linux.

and then I ported them to my MIPS development board. lua and other modules (such as luafilesystem, md5, cgilua and wsapi) run well. but lsqlite3 does not work.

when I execute require("lsqlite3") in lua command line, it returns error messages in below:

## lua

Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

> require("lsqlite3")
>   do_page_fault() #2: sending SIGSEGV to lua for invalid read access from
>   00000000 (epc == 00000000, ra == 2ac36144)
>   Segmentation fault

can any one give me any help to fix it? Thanks!

I got few progress in solving this problem, I rebuilt the LUA with gcc compile option '-Wl,-E' and rebuilt lsqlite3 later. I executed require ("lsqlite3") in lua command line, and it didnt print any message. I continued running some other database operation commands and found them all been successfully executed. As it seemed the problem had been solved, I should be very happy about it. 
but another more strange problem raised.

If I put sentence require("lsqlite3") into a file, and then execute the file in this way:

> lua file

it still printed  error messages like this:

> do_page_fault() #2: sending SIGSEGV to lua for invalid read access from
>   2ada054c (epc == 2ada054c, ra == 2abdceac)

If I put more database operation sentences into a file, and then run this file by lua. Lua can give correct result of query operation and insert values to table correctly, but always print error messages showed above.

If I run sentences in the file one by one in lua command line interface, it never print this error message.

It seems to give the error message when executing the 'require' function. But if I put require("lfs") into a file and run this file by lua, it never print error message.

I am confused that whait is the difference between the lua command line execution and lua script.

Comment: Can you run it under gdb, or another debugger, and get a backtrace from the thread interrupted by the SIGSEGV?

Comment: Also, is sqlite3 installed and usable from the command line?

Comment: Thanks, sqlite3 has already been installed into the development board , and I can create database and tables from the sqlite3 command line.

Comment: I think I had found the problem.

Comment: I think I had found the problem.  I tried to use luasql-sqlite3 for replacement, but got the same error. while compiling luqsql-sqlite3, it gave a warning  "sqlite3.h:253: warning: ISO C90 does not support `long long'"  . so I went back to lsqlite3 and compiled it again with option '-petantic' enabled. it gave the same warning. The Sqlite3 may need type long long, but the gcc I used for my board seems not support this feature.  even though how can I solve this problem if I was unable to change the toolchain for this board?

Answer (score 0):

There are three places in `lsqlite3.c` where `sqlite_int64` is used (never `long long` directly). When you build sqlite3 some type will be used for 64 bit integers; lsqlite3 will use the same type by including `sqlite3.h` for the definition of the type.